# How to host Flutter App Data files online?

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on a workout app, the app has a lot of exercise images, 30 background music files making the build file bigger. How to reduce this ? Where can I host the in-app data files?

Answer (score 1):

Host files to Firebase Storage or Amazon S3 or another service.
Use flutter_cache_manager and cached_network_image to download when needed.
The files are big. http://wasabi.com price is 80% lower than Amazon S3. Bandwidth is free on Wasabi and your data is on SSD.

Comment: can I use firebase realtime database to store app data like day-1 exercises json, day -2 json..etc. the workouts are same for all users  along with firebase storage ? Sorry, I am a newbie to this?